# autofill using indirect function (google sheet 2016)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have an issue with rendering auto-fill active using the formula hereby using Google Sheets.

Basically, I have like a ton of rows so I need to be able to have the formula be autocompleted by dragging it down otherwise I am going to go insane.

I already checked the formula, it works, but "Sourcing!J**??**" needs to change as I drag it along and in my case everything remains fixed for some reason.

I believe the quotes are responsible for this but when i remove them the formula doesn't work anymore.

> Blockquote
>   EXAMPLE:

`=countif(indirect("Sourcing!J14");"Europe (EU + Switzerland + Norway + UK)")`

> Blockquote

Comment: i'am quite unfamiliar with Gsheets, but I have no choice but to use them. I was wondering also, if I should envisage using INDEX instead of INDIRECT to lock it the referencing to the other sheet.

Comment: Also i read about the possibility of using this formula: "=ArrayFormula( Blad!1A2:A )" but not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after hours of gsearch and adapted it to 2016 ! :-) so sharing it here: you will easily find online answers to this question, but most of them aren't valid for the 2016 version of Sheets so here you go : mainly, the ADRESS function solves the issues and also you need to replace your usual "," with ";" in the v2016 GSheets.

`=countif(indirect("Sourcing!"&CELL("address";K2));"Yes")`

Comment: Thank you for this example, it was helpful. But"," with ";"  depends on your regional settings. Go to `file > Settings` to check them. And provided solution is not an ArrayFunction (autofill). Do you need to make the formula be autocompleted?